# Gradle sync failed: set process working directory to '/Users/apple/Android/Android app': could not setcwd() (errno 2: No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

After cleaning up my laptop using 3rd party software, this error shows up:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not set process working directory to '/Users/apple/Desktop/Matrix/Android/Android app': could not setcwd() (errno 2: No such file or directory)
```

I've already tried Invalidate Cache/Re-start and setting local gradle file via configuration and none of them seem to work.

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not set process working directory to '/Users/apple/Desktop/Matrix/Android/Matrix Android app': could not setcwd() (errno 2: No such file or directory)
```

Due to this I can't run the app or build. Please help